# Why aren't we using two fragment constructor to create a new instance and instead using a static method?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I see that on google's example for creating a new fragment is through a static method called newInstance. But why aren't we using two constructors to achieve the same thing as below?

ie.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public MyFragment() {
    }

    public MyFragment(String name) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_NAME, name);
        setArguments(bundle);
    }
}

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public MyFragment() {
    }

    public static MyFragment newInstance(String name) {
        MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_NAME, name);
        myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return myFragment;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has been discussed on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Comment: @JonGoodwin it's more related to the answer below. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994861/1915831. Also, this isn't one constructor solution I'm trying solve. I do understand the impact of having one constructor and why it would be bad.